# IIS redirect mangling URL parameter value occasionally

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

We have a multi-tenant application with a Web server in the following environment:

- Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter
- IIS 7.5
- ASP.NET 4.5
- All traffic forced into HTTPS
- Forms authentication

We have some convenience redirects in place in the site's Web.config file. For one of the redirects, the **URL parameter value is being mangled occassionally** (< 1%) on the **request immediately following the 301 redirect**.

The rule is intended to redirect URLs such as https://www.myapp.com/some_client_id/notifications to https://www.myapp.com/lms/profile/notifications.aspx?cid=some_client_id

Here is its definition:

```
<rule name="Redirect profile notifications page" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/notifications/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="lms/profile/notifications.aspx?cid={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Looking at the WWW logs, I see something along the lines of:

```
2014-07-03 09:40:19 W3SVC2 a.b.c.d GET /some_client_id/notifications - 443 - w.x.y.z Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) - - www.myapp.com 301 0 0 581 297 156
2014-07-03 09:40:19 W3SVC2 a.b.c.d GET /lms/profile/notifications.aspx cid=mang_ledch_rs 443 - w.x.y.z Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) - - www.myapp.com 302 0 0 693 277 109
2014-07-03 09:40:19 W3SVC2 a.b.c.d GET /lms/login.aspx ReturnUrl=%2flms%2fprofile%2fnotifications.aspx%3fcid%3dmang_ledch_rs&cid=mang_ledch_rs 443 - w.x.y.z Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) - - www.myapp.com 200 0 0 7173 336 218
```

When the client ID value is mangled, it:

- happens across a number of clients but predominantly at the same ones
- mangles to the same characters (for example, 'j' is mangled to 'w', 'l' is mangled to 'y')

I'm not able to reproduce the issue but it happens a few times a day. Using Fiddler, I don't see anything out of the ordinary when making similar requests.

**Any ideas on what is causing this?** If not, do you have suggestions for how to debug this? Thanks.

Comment: I have this issue too, but on a completely different stack. I only see the issue occurring with IE9 clients. Notice that each mangled character is exactly +13 characters from the original (j + 13 = w, l + 13 = y) I have this exact same symptom.

Comment: See my related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486730/mangled-url-parameters-in-ie9

Comment: @Salami: This is still an ongoing issue for us. We suspect it is the result of email link-checking software installed at some of our clients.

Comment: thanks. Would be nice to know which link-checking software does this.

Comment: Your problem description seems to match the rot13 in @Salami's question; can you confirm that it's actually the same? a->m, b->n, c->o etc.

Comment: Yes, the characters are always shifted by 13 characters. Some are +13, while the rest are -13. I hadn't noticed this before.

Comment: I suspect that it is link-checking software that is using ROT13 encryption for parameter values to avoid performing actions when following links (such as unsubscribing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confident that this issue is the result of email link-checking software that is using ROT13 encryption on link parameter values to avoid performing actions, such as unsubscribing.