# Recognize the pattern: what system is malforming my query string parameters?

Tags: query-string, querystringparameter, malformed

We have a fairly complicated ASP.NET MVC project with cross domain login widgets and a lot of semi-legacy code.

There is a system where we login people through an iframe. The url for the iframe we send through a string attached to the MVC Model.

Problem is; on really rare occassions we see malformed query string parameters coming through. It's always the same malformation though. I want to fix the issue, but I can't figure out why this happens.

I'm expecting some Adblocker-type or privacy settings, or maybe some Regional settings, but I have no clue where to start.

I am hoping someone will recognize the pattern and say; that's a localization pattern when your Windows is set on Turkey or whatever, you should check your encoding etc etc.

Anyway here's the example:

```
Expected:
    auth-dialog-window?openerOrigin=https%3a%2f%2f.poules.com&color=C3042E&openerType=iframe
Coming through:
    auth-dialog-window?color=P304212R&openerType=vsenzr&openerOrigin=uggcf%3N%2S%2Scbhyrf.pbz
```

Apparently the order of the query string also changes. Here more closely per parameter:

```
iframe
vsenzr

https://      poules.com (spaces are for aligning)
uggcf%3N%2S%2Scbhyrf.pbz

C3042E
P304212R
```

Does anyone recognize the pattern and can give me a hint where I should be looking?

I know for sure the last time it happened with IE 9.0, but can't reproduce it.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656616/1846192)

Comment: Thanks @MathijsFlietstra, that was a great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROT-13.

A system somewhere is "trying to crypt" in a very simple way...

Check "pairs" of letters in both values:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: whow, clever - but the followup why would any browser/system/antivirus do a rot13 on our query string parameters?

Comment: A: User agent, to avoid making obvious for the user those parameters in a GET request.
B: Some kind of automatic agent (sear engine crawler, bots, spam software...) to avoid "actions" been taken when following the link
...

Comment: Give a chance to a "find" in your source code for "rot" and "13", maybe that could give you a clue. check http://www.brettb.com/rot13_encoding_with_asp.asp to see and old implementation (you said something about legacy code)

Comment: @DirkBoer: I had a look at the link in the comment under your question, the link pointed to another question which also had a "related" link commented underneath too. Following *that* link, I found a question that the asker closed by concluding link-checking software in email was to blame. Are the links in question getting emailed? (Not necessarily by you, but by your users)

Comment: @DirkBoer: if this continues without any easy/obvious fix, a longer-term "hard mode" option might be to look into temporarily dropping a supercookie tracker into your page (IIUC supercookies are "clear data"-resilient, sounds good for debugging) to narrow down who this is happening to, then you could see about possibly getting in touch with the affected user(s) and asking about their configuration. If you go this route, maybe post what software they're using :) (in this and the other threads, perhaps)

Comment: For me the reffered link was superuseful. Now it is confirmed that this can be caused by antimalware software and they always use ROT13, I'm going to build a check in for that and make sure it doesn't throw exceptions to our logs.